# Chrome Link Preview Doesn't Disappear When Mouseout

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser

Mouseover an a tag with chrome, it displays a href text at the bottom left corner, but sometimes after mouseout, the text display doesn't disappear, and sometimes it changed to display another link.
What cause the problem? Is it chrome's bug or related to some tips that frond-end designer should follow?

Comment: provide your code :)

Comment: @Cattla not my code, it happened on almost all the websites, yahoo, google, and even stackoverflow here, but I found it seems that facebook seldom makes it happen... cannot know why. Originally I was thinking something like a tag wrapped in a particular html tag which causes this, but never figure it out eventually.